# how to refresh specific div content and content comes from ajax page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, modal-dialog

I want to refresh div content. When i change the product quantity and div content present in **modal dialog**(comes from ajax page) but it's not working. pls let me know how can i do this.

**load modal from ajax page**

```
function getbasket(){
    $(".loader").show();
    $.get("{{url('basket')}}",
    function(success){
        $("#cartContent").html(success);
        $(".loader").removeAttr("disabled");
        $(".loader").fadeOut(1000);
    });
}
```

**call this function when change the product quantity**

```
function updateCart(obj){
    $(".loader").show();
    $.post("{{url('cart-update')}}",
    {
        rowId : obj,
        cartQty : $("#cartQty").val()
    },
    function(success){
        $( "#table_content" ).load(window.location.href + " #table_content" );
        $(".loader").removeAttr("disabled");
        $(".loader").fadeOut(1000);
    });
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try just running the getbasket() function again inside of the success function?

```
function updateCart(obj){
    $(".loader").show();
    $.post("{{url('cart-update')}}",
    {
        rowId : obj,
        cartQty : $("#cartQty").val()
    },
    function(success){
        getbasket();
    });
}
```

Alternatively I would look at using Angular for this as it binds the data to a model and handles the updating for you.

Comment: Awesome! :) And definitely check out Angular if you are doing lots of work like this, I am just learning it myself but see a huge potential, especially to save on load times as the way this is set up now the whole div needs to be reloaded so with Angular just the specific property would be updated :)